# PayPal Seamless Checkout (Login with PayPal) with setExpressCheckout API call

Tags: paypal

I am trying to integrate the seamless checkout customer flow in our website, whereby a customer can Login with PayPal, then proceed to a make a payment without having to login again.

I have my Login with PayPal Rest app running, and working.
I also have my Classic API (using the merchantsdk library) call for setExpressCheckout that works.

The documentation states that I should be passing in an IDENTITYACCESSTOKEN parameter. However, this doesn't seem to be available in the sdk. Am I missing something?

Kind Regards,
Damian

Answer (score 5):

I know this is coming pretty late but here's the answer: (hope it helps someone)

I have outlined all the steps from the start as follows: (I am assuming you already have a basic expresschekout app working and you want to integrate Login with PayPal to have seamless checkout)

1) Have the Login with PayPal REST App registered on developer.paypal.com : make a new REST app, fill in the required details. And if you want login with paypal with expresscheckout , then make sure to enable the seamless checkout. You will find it under Login with PayPal -click on Advanced options next to it. Also, the parameters available for checking like basic authentication, Personal Information,
Address information, etc. are called scopes and will be of importance later on. You can check all of them. Also, make sure to provide a privacy info url and user agreement url. The app will not work without them. (For dev purposes, a url of your website say https://example.com/privacy.html etc. will work.)

2) For embedding the Login with PayPal button on your website (for more info, see this: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/button/) 
and here's a link to the dynamic builder form: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/button-js-builder/

Here's what the generated code looks like:

```
<span id="myContainer"></span>
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/api.js"></script>
<script>
            paypal.use( ["login"], function(login) {
              login.render ({
                "appid": "isaufdiudshfjdsfkjhuwAHsgdnGn",
                "authend": "sandbox",
                "scopes": "openid profile email address phone https://uri.paypal.com/services/paypalattributes https://uri.paypal.com/services/expresscheckout",
                "containerid": "myContainer",
                "locale": "en-us",
                "returnurl": "https://localhost/dp/loggedin.php"
              });
            });
            </script>
```

These scopes are correct when you have checked all the scopes (basic auth, address, etc) available on developer.paypal.com in you app. The scope "https://uri.paypal.com/services/expresscheckout" is for seamlesscheckout. Caution: If the scopes are different on the developer paypal website and in this generated code, then you will get a scope mismatch error.

3) So, if all works well, after this you should be having a "Login with PayPal" button on your website and when you click it, you should see a Paypal login window opening. When you login using some sandbox account (assuming you are using sandbox) , then you will get  aconsent form and when you say agree and continue, it should take you back to the return URL. And here's the core part: 
In the return URL they will send you a parameter called "code". This is the authorization code.

4) Now you have to obtain the Identity Access Token from the authorization code. Here are the steps for this: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#grant-token-from-authorization-code

And a sample request which works for me (Replace with your credentials) :

```
 curl -v --insecure api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/tokenservice -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Accept-Language: en_US" -d "client_id=PjewirksjfhnIksjdlkjskfljds" -d "client_secret=Abcdsffudkjjhirgjkljgkldfjglkdlgd" -d "grant_type=authorization_code" -d "code=asdkajhAkjdksA" gYIXH-FJb1-piZEAXIif4PGAumOeEenS9cjX4rdKfOi6tyuzqRoyGJvFhzrIdI8JYO2aDO3Emtwdv1w‌​L0SSksPbcJJsHsnEKrCjEsh8yscuotBS7vV3HSSLLnl"
```

By this you get the Identity Access Token in "access_token" field. You will also get refresh_token (explained later)

4) This access_token is what you need to pass in the setexpresscheckout request.
A sample request can be found on this page: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/seamless-checkout/

5) Also, remember, the access_token expires in some time. So, you need to get new access token by using the refresh token mentioned in step 3. But for basic working, till step 4 should get you through. All the best :)